# Is [{:keys [:a]}] or [{:keys [a]}] more idiomatic destructuring?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

What are the differences between the two following forms?

```
(defn abc [{:keys [:a]}] a)
(defn abc [{:keys [a]}]  a)
```

Is there one that is more idiomatic?

Comment: I'd argue, that with symbols (second example) is basically the only one that works with the `:syms` and `:strs` (e.g. `(let [{:strs ["a"]} {"a" 1}] a)` fails)

Answer (score 1):

Map destructuring with :keys us usually done with symbols, like in your second example.

I'm not entirely sure of this claim, but I think support for keywords in :keys was added specifically to support the case of destructuring namespaced keywords with namespace aliases, that is:

```
(ns (require [com.company.foo :as foo]
             ... ))

(defn abc [{:keys [::foo/a]}] a)
```

Comment: `(let [{:keys [foo/a]} {:foo/a 1}] a) => 1`

Comment: Note that :foo/a and ::foo/a are not the same. In my case foo is a namespace alias. I don't know if this changed in a more recent version of clojure but last time I checked foo in :foo/a doesn't check aliases (in the :: it does)

Comment: In 1.9 you can use the `(let [{:foo/keys [a]} #:foo{:a 1}] a) ;=> 1` syntax as well.

Comment: @Setzer22 wow, didn't know about this "feature". Now I see. Thanks.